# javascript number always 2 digits decimal in typeof Number format

Tags: javascript, numbers, decimal

I read through many answers for this question on this platform but none of them gives result that I need.

If I use Javascript toFixed(2), it makes it string and I strickly need Number format:

For Example:

```
Value = 4
```

The output I get when I use toFixed is "4.00"

But I need 4.00 (number format for the charts)

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: 4.00 as a Number is 4

Comment: What you want isn't possible. Numbers are abstract quantities. They don't get decimal points and precision until you format them, and that's a string.

Comment: If you're using charting software, it may have its own options to format the numbers.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I found a solution in API itself.

Answer (score 0):

That function is to convert a number in a string.

Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp

What do you want (a number format) is the function: `parseInt()`

Examples here:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp

You can check the type of a variable with `typeof` operator.
Example:

```
Value = 4
console.log('Value type:', typeof Value);
```